# poor quality audio playback in javascript windows store app

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-store-apps, html5-audio, windows-8.1

I'm programming a Windows Store app using javascript and having trouble playing audio without poor quality. Usually when a sound plays it sounds as if it is skipping the first few hundred milliseconds of the sound (and sometimes more), resulting in clicks and sometimes almost no sound (because the sound files are short). I have 8 short files (27kb .mp3). The weirdest thing is that the volume of the playback also seems to randomly vary between a quiet and loud level. I'm using a Windows 8.1 tablet with a 1.6GHz processor.

```
//I declare like this:
var playList = new Array("chord1.mp3", "chord2.mp3", "chord3.mp3", "chord4.mp3", "chord5.mp3", "chord6.mp3", "chord7.mp3", "chord8.mp3" );
var playListIndex = 0;
var players = new Array();

//I initialise like this:
        for (var i = 0; i < playList.length; i++) {
            players[i] = new Audio();
            players[i].src = playList[i];
        }

//When it's time to play (listening for pointerdown events) I do this:           
        players[playListIndex].play();

//I have tried this but it just introduces latency without solving the problem
        //new Audio(playList[playListIndex]).play();

//This happens after playing to make the sounds play sequentially.
//The problems occur even when there is no overlap of playback
        playListIndex++;
        if (playListIndex >= playList.length) {
            playListIndex = 0;
        }
```

There is almost nothing else going on in the app. Suggestions much appreciated.